# Server Authentication failed (SVN / Jenkins) Maven release

Tags: linux, maven, ssl, svn, jenkins

I have an issue when releasing builds for a newly configured Jenkins. Whenever a SVN Commit is issued, it runs into an error for "Server verification failed: issuer is not trusted"

I have tried the multiple methods of svn checkout, svn list, etc. and to permanently accept the certificate information (fingerprint), but to no avail..

Is there something else I can do or I can allow, without compromising on security by disabling ssl?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the SVN plugin? or you try to clone the repo from batch/shell with SVN Checkout?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a self-signed CA certificate is in use. Add the self-signed CA certificate to the Jenkin's JDK and the JDK used by the build.  $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts

[Add CA to JDK cacerts file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep2.html)